# nhibernate mapping by code, mapping entity with list of value objects

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have entity which has many data sources.

```
public class MyData
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<DataSource> Sources { get; set; }
   public MyData(){
       Sources = new List<DataSource>();
   }
}
```

and I have DataSource class which represents value object of MyData entity

```
public class DataSource
{
   public enum SourceEnum { dataOneSrc = 1, dataTwoSrc = 2}
   public virtual SourceEnum Source { get; set; }
   public virtual string InternalRefNr { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using nhibernate orm and its mapping by code approach. 
So I mapped value object using this link as ref.
//http://lycog.com/programming/nhibernate-32-mapping-code-component-mapping/

```
public static Action<IComponentMapper<DataSource>> Mapping()
{
    return c =>{
                c.Property(p => p.Source);
                c.Property(p => p.InternalRefNr, m =>
                {
                    m.Length(255);
                });                    
            };
    }
```

and entity mapping using

```
public MyData()
{
    ...
    Bag<DataSource>(x => x.Sources,
        c => { },
        r =>{ r.OneToMany();}
    );
}
```

I'm getting **Nhibernate.MappingException**

{"Association references unmapped class: *My.Model.DataSource"}*

Comment: But is not this exception really clear? You just have to mapp the `DataSource` as well. That's it

Comment: I mapped DataSource above, public static Action<IComponentMapper<DataSource>> Mapping()

Comment: can you please post as an answer how would you map entity, with list of value objects

Comment: I provided some draft of the mapping and few essential links to Adam's Bar mapping by code. That should enlighten that matter a bit...

Comment: thanks for the effort, but I made design choice to make DataSource as an value object (not an entity). Do you have some advices on that manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COMPOSITE ELEMENT

If we do not want to map separated entity, we cannot use `one-to-many`. We need:

[6.3. Collections of Values and Many-To-Many Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues) (small cite)

> For a collection of values, we use the  tag.

```
<element
        column="column_name"                (1)
        type="typename"                     (2)
/>
```

> ...
>
> A list of components (discussed in the next chapter):

```
<list name="CarComponents" table="car_components">
    <key column="car_id"/>
    <index column="posn"/>
    <composite-element class="Eg.Car.CarComponent">
            <property name="Price" type="float"/>
            <property name="Type" type="Eg.Car.ComponentType, Eg"/>
            <property name="SerialNumber" column="serial_no" type="String"/>
    </composite-element>
</list>
```

So in our case, we cannot use one-to-many but **`Component`**:

```
// instead of this
r =>{ r.OneToMany();}
// we need this for IList<string>
r.Element(e => { });
// this for DataSource as in the above question
r.Component(c => { });
```

ONE-TO-MANY:

The mapping by code should go like this: [Hibernate's Mapping by Code](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-first.html). 
Any entity should have surrogate key (Id). That should be the DataSource:

```
public class DataSource
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string InternalRefNr { get; set; }
   public virtual MyDataMyData{ get; set; }
}
```

The mapping of that class then could be:

```
public class DataSourceMap : DataSourceMapping<DataSource>
{
    public DataSourceMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        Property(x => x.InternalRefNr);
        ManyToOne(x => x.MyData);
    }
}
```

And now we can map `MyData` based on [Mapping-by-Code - Set and Bag](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html)

```
public MyData()
{
    ...
    Bag<DataSource>(x => x.Sources,
        c => { c.Inverse(true); },
        r =>{ r.OneToMany();}
    );
}
```

Comment: yep, but I dont want DataSource to be an entity. It should represent value object in this context.

Comment: Ok, then you should **NOT** use `OneToMany` - [6.3. Collections of Values and Many-To-Many Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-ofvalues):  *For a collection of values, we use the '<element>' tag.* or *A list of components (discussed in the next chapter): `<composite-element>`*

Comment: I extended the answer with all the details. NHibernate can map `IList<string>`  with `<element>` and also virtual entity with `<composite-element>`... hope this will help